# create a text box accepting only 0-9 and get these numbers appear in another text box by adding "1" to each number

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I  have two text box fields , I created the first one accepting numbers only from 0-9 by regular Expression and get them appears again in a second text box field; 
 I need when you type any number in the first text box field, these numbers appear in the second text box by adding "1" to each number

for example: 
when you input "0" in the first field ==> the second field shows "1" 
when you input "1" in the first field ==> the second field shows "2"
..... 
when you input "9" in the first field ==> alert appears to tell you that "the series is ended, you cannot type 9"

this is the JS code

```
   var n1 = document.getElementById('numbers-1').value,
       n2 = document.getElementById('numbers-2').value;

    function numbersOnly(input) {
        var regex2 = /[^0-9]/;
        input.value = input.value.replace(regex2, "");

        var n2 = document.getElementById('numbers-1').value;
        document.getElementById('numbers-2').value = n2;
    }
```

and this is the HTML Code

```
  <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="numbers-1" oninput="numbersOnly(this)"><br>
  <input type="text" id="numbers-2">
```

thanks guys

Comment: I am a beginner in JS and this task is assigned to me in unpaid internship, i made the validation in form and cannot make the second step after many times, thanks anyway Jorge :)

Comment: @samoscieno check out my answer

Comment: @Sarfraaz it works better well for numbers 1-8 ; but if you put "0" nothing happens, and if you put "9" the message appears well but after you put ok for the message; "9" appears in the box

Comment: @samoscieno I have updated the answer, check it out now

Comment: @Sarfraaz the first field should only accepts characters 0-9 , the validation does not work, also when you  type "9" after putting series of numbers; the alert does not work

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,
let me know if any more explanation needed

```js
function numbersOnly(input) {
    var regex2 = /[^0-9]/;
    var val = parseInt(input.replace(regex2, ""));
    if(!isNaN(val)) {
      if(val.toString().indexOf('9') > -1) {
        document.getElementById('numbers-1').value = "";
        document.getElementById('numbers-2').value = "";
        alert('the series is ended, you cannot type 9');
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById('numbers-2').value = val+1;
      }
    } else {
       document.getElementById('numbers-1').value = "";
       document.getElementById('numbers-2').value = "";
    }
     
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="numbers-1" oninput="numbersOnly(this.value)"><br>
  <input type="text" id="numbers-2">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input ng-model="number" type="number" max="9" min="0" ng-keyup="print()" required><br><br>
<input ng-model="answer" type="number">
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.print = function()
    {
        if($scope.number >= 9)
        {
            alert('the series is ended, you cannot type 9');
            $scope.number = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.answer= $scope.number + 1;
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is for normal javascript, not in angular.

Comment: so what they want solution and there is not much more diff between angular js and javascript